# Executing a process from azure app service

Tags: process, grpc, azure-web-app-service, execute

I'm running a process to generate c# classes using GRPC tool from proto file. The code works fine on my development machine but once deployed on azure the process runs but returns a `ExitCode = -1073740791` and the output is string empty.

I've logged the command I execute and if I try to execute in `Kudu` console it works fine and the c# files are generated as expected.

The command looks like:

```
Tools\bin\tools\windows_x86\protoc.exe 
-ID:\local\LocalAppData\GrpcTester\0969261f-bfa7-45a8-bba1-7e1ccd3818e7\protos 
--csharp_out=D:\local\LocalAppData\GrpcTester\0969261f-bfa7-45a8-bba1-7e1ccd3818e7\csharpfiles 
--grpc_out=D:\local\LocalAppData\GrpcTester\0969261f-bfa7-45a8-bba1-7e1ccd3818e7\csharpfiles 
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="Tools\bin\tools\windows_x86\grpc_csharp_plugin.exe" 
D:\local\LocalAppData\GrpcTester\0969261f-bfa7-45a8-bba1-7e1ccd3818e7\protos\mobile_backend.proto
```

```
private bool GenerateGRPCCSharpFiles(TestProject testProject)
        {
            bool succes = false;
            var outputFolder = WorkspaceManager.GetProjectSubFolder(testProject.Id.ToString(), WorkspaceManager.CSharpFilesPath);
            var protoFilesFolder = WorkspaceManager.GetProjectSubFolder(testProject.Id.ToString(), WorkspaceManager.ProtosPath);


            // Install tools
            RequireTools().Wait();

            var protoc = ProtocPath();
            var plugin = ProtocPluginPath();
            logger.LogDebug($"GenerateGRPCCSharpFiles : protoc: {protoc}");
            logger.LogDebug($"GenerateGRPCCSharpFiles : plugin: {plugin}");

            //string protocol = Path.Combine(protoFilesFolder, protoFiles.FirstOrDefault().FileName);
            string protocol = Directory.GetFiles(protoFilesFolder).FirstOrDefault();

            var command = new string[]
            {
                $"-I{protoFilesFolder}",
                $"--csharp_out={outputFolder}",
                $"--grpc_out={outputFolder}",
                $"--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=\"{plugin}\"",
                protocol,
            };


            try
            {
                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = protoc;
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Join(' ', command);
                    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream))
                    {
                        var response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        logger.LogDebug($"GenerateGRPCCSharpFiles: Completed output: {response.ToString()}");
                    }

                    succes = process.ExitCode == 0;

                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return succes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something related to [Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) of app service . Follow [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) for more information.

Comment: It looks like Sandbox problem. The problem I have is that the command runs in `Kudu` but when is executed from the application returns exit code ** -1073740791**. I don't know what this code means.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the RedirectStandardOutput (stupid mistake) wich has to be executed before WaitForExit. See the modified code:

```
                process.StartInfo.FileName = protoc;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Join(' ', command);

                //You must set UseShellExecute to false if you want to set RedirectStandardOutput to true.
                //Otherwise, reading from the StandardOutput stream throws an exception.
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                string eOut = null;
                process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) => { eOut += e.Data; });

                process.Start();

                // To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.
                // To avoid deadlocks, use an asynchronous read operation on at least one of the streams.
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                logger.LogDebug($"GenerateGRPCCSharpFiles: Completed output: {output.ToString()}");

                process.WaitForExit();
```